# where is pldebugger extension?

Tags: postgresql, debugging, pgadmin

New to postgreSQL and pgadmin4, I wanted to use the debugger. It says it need a server extension.
Searching on internet it always talk about this :

```
"https://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git"
```

Unfortunately, it seems this project has disappeared. Does that mean that we cannot use debugger in pgAdmin ever ?

Is there another extension somewhere, I cannot find it.

Note : OS is CentOS Linux 7

Thank you

Comment: Seems like it has moved to Github: https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/pldebugger

Comment: is there another one. it looks like it cannot be added on postgresql 13 and centos 7.8

Comment: Open an issue and ask, showing what exactly you tried and what error you hot.

Comment: it seems to be working for postgresql version 9. We are version 13. It is too old.

Comment: The [latest commit](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/pldebugger/commit/0b35ef2eef2a2fe53a120a72ae519cce5ee749a0), some 4 months age, addressed compatibility with v14. Go and ask them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it in centos packages :

https://pkgs.org/download/pldebugger13